# Design out of bounds from editor history page

Tags: bug, design

I found this issue while on the revision page and the editor has a high reputation and many badges.

[image: out of bounds]

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4683716/revisions

Tried at macOS Mojave v10.14.6 on Chrome v91, FF v89, Safari v12.1.2.

And all produce same result.

Comment: Possible fix: give BalusC enough upvotes so he get 1M rep. That will shorten the string enough to fit.

Comment: No repro on FF90

Comment: no repro FF ESR https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ek2p.png

Comment: @frianH VLAZ was simply telling what is referred to as, a joke

Comment: Safari v12.1.2 is quite old. It was released in July of 2019. The latest is v14.1.1, and [is apparently available on Mojave](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/05/04/apple-releases-safari-14-1-update/).

Comment: No apparent repro on Win10 Chrome v91

Comment: [Job done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1H95.png), I guess...

Comment: There are [more serious problems with the revision history page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2725154/revisions) (false "positives"). Is there a meta question for it?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes there are serious problem there, like not change, but I don't know about the question.

Comment: I found it. It was posted a few hours before on MSE: *[Revision histories of posts show headings being removed and re-added every single revision, even if they aren't changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367394)*